# Bluetooth transfer from PC to Android through RFCOMM

Tags: android-ndk

I am trying to stream data from a laptop to native code in an android 
phone. 
Am able to pair with laptop and get data for sometime, but the native 
code crashes with the following message later:

"failed adding to JNI pinned array ref table".

Code snippet:
// Java code for Bluetooth read handler
case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // Send the data in the buffer to native code
                sendData(readBuf, msg.arg1);
........................................................................

// C-code:
...sendData  (JNIEnv *env, jclass cl, jbyteArray arr, jint size)
{
.....
jbyte *buffer = (jbyte*)env->GetByteArrayElements(arr, &isCopy);
....// copy the buffer to a local variable.
if (isCopy == JNI_TRUE) {
env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(arr,  buffer, JNI_ABORT);

}

What could be wrong? 
I am already using similar code for array transfer between Java and C 
elsewhere in the code, and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved. 
Actually, the "other" portion which i am referring to had the problem.

Instead of GetByteArrayElements(), used GetByteArrayRegion() so that 
there is no pinning problem.